# How to extract values from multiple tags in Scrapy selector?

Tags: beautifulsoup, scrapy

```
<div class="information-list__item l-column small-12 medium-6 large-4 small-valign-top">
          <dt class="information-list__item__term medium-valign-top">Supplier</dt>
          <dd class="information-list__item__definition">
            Elmar Groetsch
          </dd>
        </div>
```

In Scrapy or BeautifulSoup, how to extract values 'Supplier' & 'Elmar Groetsch'? In this case, Supplier is the key and Elmar Groetsch is the value.

This doesn't do the job:

```
supplier = response.css('div.information-list__item')[0]
```

How to use the multiple tags in the class="" part?

Answer (score 0):

These will return supplier and Elmar Groetsch, respectively

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.find('div', class_='information-list__item l-column small-12 medium-6 large-4 small-valign-top').find('dt').text
soup.find('div', class_='information-list__item l-column small-12 medium-6 large-4 small-valign-top').find('dd').text
```

Comment: I am using scrape. What's the equivalent way to do that?

Comment: you asked about either program, i don't use scrapy but you can try response.css('dt.information-list__item__term.medium-valign-top')[0].text
response.css('dd.information-list__item__definition')[0].text